# how to presigned URL for an Amazon S3 object and let it expires after one week?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface

According to the [guide](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/presigned-url-s3-bucket-expiration/), I have designated IAM user credentials (the access key and secret access key) and generated a presigned URL using AWS Signature Version 4 like this:

```py
import os
os.system('aws configure set access_key {} --profile {}'.format(my_access_key, profile_name))
os.system('aws configure set secret_key {} --profile {}'.format(my_secret_key, profile_name))
os.system('aws configure set signature_version s3v4 --profile {}'.format(profile_name))
os.system("aws s3 presign {} --expires-in 604800 > public_url --profile {}".format(s3_path, profile_name))
```

However, the url still expired after 6 hours. Is there any wrong in my code or if the credential I used is not belong to IAM user? How can I check the credential types (IAM user or AWS IAM instance profile)? I just follow [the steps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/pstools-appendix-sign-up.html) to get my access key and secret access key

Comment: The `my_access_key` and `my_secret_key` are from your IAM users, or some IAM role?

Comment: I just follow the steps(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/pstools-appendix-sign-up.html) to get the keys. They are from my IAM user.

Comment: Then I don't see a reason why it would expire in 6h only. How did you test it?

Comment: I click the url after 6 hours and the page shows "The provided token has expired."

Comment: Can you verify using aws cli? Don't use python, just do it all manually in terminal and check if its same.

Comment: I can try it. But the two result urls using python or cli seem to have the same parameters.  And even using cli works, it does not solve my problem since the proceduce must be automatic and I don't want to do this manually.

Comment: The only reason I can think off that your url expires early, is because you are using IAM role to make it. pre-sign url are valid for only as long as the entity that made them (role or iam user).

Comment: Yes, this is the most likely reason since the url expires after exactly 6 hours. But I don't know how to check my account is a IAM user or AWS IAM instance profile.

Comment: If you took your IAM credentails from IAM console, then its IAM user. Why do you think its IAM instance profile?

Comment: Because 6 hours correspond to the IAM instance profile according to the doc(https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/presigned-url-s3-bucket-expiration/)

Comment: So this goes back to the first qustion: "The my_access_key and my_secret_key are from your IAM users, or some IAM role?" You wrote you followed the link. The link is about IAM users, not roles.

Comment: This is why i am so confused about this issue.

Comment: First clarify, are you runnign this code on EC2 instance or not?

Comment: my code runs on EMR.

Comment: It seems that I have to make MFA first